# How to manage sessions in web-driven Iphone Application

Tags: iphone, web-services, session, rss, authentication

I am Making an Iphone application which is web-service enabled. Also I have skeleton of this application.I am using rest to feed the contents of view controllers. When application is launched it is presented with Login page asking username and password. Clicking Login button sends request to server and in response xml data is fetched. Then I parse this data to get user logged. But i dont know how will i manage sessions,and how clicking logout button will end this session. This application is most-like RSSFeeder,means user gets real-time data.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.Thank You All.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it seems obvious you are using REST connection,you need not take session in consideration.
just feed your username and password and other stuff in the URLRequest and make connections.
You can also use Setting perferences in settings.Bundle to autofeed your URLRequest.

Comment: yeah i was thinking the same, but was not sure. Thank you KayKay.